# how to activate vim folding markers?

Tags: vim, configuration, folding

I have inherited some c++ code with vim-based folding markers like this:

```
// CONSTRUCTORS/DESTRUCTORS /*{{{*/
Foo::Foo()
{
}
Foo::~Foo()
{
}
/*}}}*/
```

*What do I need to put into my .vimrc to enable folding toggles like zm and space-bar?*

With my current settings, when I hit space bar inside or zm, vim does nothing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default keybindings for folding are `za` or `zm` (though `zm` I think only closes folds, while `za` toggles them), so you should add the following lines to your .vimrc:

`set foldmethod=marker` to enable folding triggered by markers (the `{{{` things in your code)

`nnoremap <space> za` to enable `space` to trigger the fold in normal mode.

But! if you're not sure if you want to enable folding in other files, you could use `autocmd`s, like so:

`autocmd FileType vim,c++,txt setlocal foldmethod=marker`and that will ensure that folding only works in vim, c++, and text files.

By the way, what you've posted is only one kind of folding mentioned by vim guru Steve Losh in [this article](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/48.html). Read it to learn more about folding. It's super cool.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after googling around for a bit, I found this which seems to work:

```
set foldmethod=marker 
nnoremap <space> za
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a few files or if you just wish to control option(s) on a per file basis you may want to use `modeline`. My intro to folding came when I download a z-shell script and when I opened it, was surprised to find everything folded. Found something like this at the end of the file:

```
# vim:ts=4:sw=4:ai:foldmethod=marker:foldlevel=0:
```

Change commenting to match your code type, and insure there is a space before the word `vim`. As always a good place to start: `:help modeline` and `:help folding`. You may have to add `set modeline` to your .vimrc file if `modeline` was not set at build time.